Why does umi add an extra characters to the beginning of the meta data?
 const umi = createUmi(rpcUrl);
 umi.use(mplTokenMetadata());
 umi.use(signerIdentity(source));

 const memo = {
     memo: '1'
 }
 
 let transaction = await transactionBuilder()
     .add(addMemo(umi, memo))
     .add(createNft(umi, {...}))
     .setFeePayer(source)
     .buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);

After signing this transaction I noticed that extra characters were added to the beginning of the memo data.


Why were they added and is there a way to prevent them from appearing in the memo data?

This is probably just an implementation detail in umi, where it interprets a memo as a borsh-style string, where it prefixes the string with the length as a little-endian u32. If you want to avoid that, you might need to propose a change to umi or add the instruction by hand
